# How to scope results from 2 different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a User model that `has_one` profile. I have the following code in my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :city, lambda { |user| joins(:profile).where(:profiles => {:city => user.profile.city})}
end
```

Then in my index action of the Users controller:

```
  def index
   @users = User.city(current_user).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
  end
```

This allows me to fetch all users from the same city as the `current_user`. What I'd also like to do is to fetch only those users that have a profile picture uploaded. I am using paperclip and the image columns are in the Users table. I wanted to add something like `show users where image_file_name != nil`. However the scope above includes the profiles tables. How can I merge the query to include a column from the Users table and one from the profiles table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join scopes together in Rails to form a final query.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :city, lambda { |user| joins(:profile).where(:profiles => {:city => user.profile.city})}
  scope :with_pictures, where('users.image_file_name IS NOT NULL')
end
```

Assuming that's what your database uses to find not-null columns.

And then in your controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.city(current_user).with_pictures.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
end
```